# Combine two dataframes with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I would like to concatenate the values of two equally shaped data frames in R (`df1` and `df2`) so that the final dataframe (`df`) contains all values separated by comma.

Here is an example

```
>df1
A B C
0 0 0
0 1 1

>df2
A B C
1 1 1
0 1 1

>df
A B C
0,1 0,1 0,1
0,0 1,1 1,1
```

Do you know any way to do it using `dplyr`?

Answer (score 1):

Base R approach -

```
df <- df1
df[] <- paste(as.matrix(df1), as.matrix(df2), sep = ",")
df

#    A   B   C
#1 0,1 0,1 0,1
#2 0,0 1,1 1,1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `tidyverse` you could first add an row id to each of your dataframes using e.g. `lapply` and `tibble::rowd_to_column`. Afterwards you could use `bind_rows`, `group_by` and `summarise`:

```r
library(dplyr)

list(df1, df2) |> 
  lapply(tibble::rowid_to_column) |> 
  bind_rows() |> 
  group_by(rowid) |> 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ paste(.x, collapse = ","))) |> 
  select(-rowid)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   A     B     C    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 0,1   0,1   0,1  
#> 2 0,0   1,1   1,1
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  A = c(0, 0),
  B = c(0, 1),
  C = c(0, 1)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  A = c(1, 0),
  B = c(1, 1),
  C = c(1, 1)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using *Map*:

```
#example data
df1 <- mtcars[1:2, 1:3]
df2 <- mtcars[3:4, 1:3]

data.frame(Map(paste, df1, df2, sep = ","))
#       mpg cyl    disp
# 1 21,22.8 6,4 160,108
# 2 21,21.4 6,6 160,258

# or mapply
#data.frame(mapply(paste, df1, df2, sep = ","))
```